# How to test cache expiration in rails with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rspec, cache-expiration

I want to test cache expiration in a Rails view. The view looks like this:

```
# products/index.html.erb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% cache product do %>
    <%= render product %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Product's partial renders owner, items, category, tags, etc. that are linked to the product. I expire cache for a product every time the product or an object linked to it gets updated

There are few ways to test cache expiration for a product:

1. Model spec: test that product's `cache_version` is being changed when updating the product or a linked object
2. View spec: test that new properties are rendered in the product's index template
3. Request spec: test that new properties are returned in the response body

`cache_version` for the Product model looks like this:

```
def cache_version
  [touched_at, updated_at].compact.map(&:utc).max.to_s(:usec)
end
```

The problem with `#1` is that somebody could change the product partial so it won't use `cache_version` method. For example, after upgrade from rails `5.1` to `5.2` caching mechanism has been changed to use `cache_version` instead of `cache_key`

What about if somebody changes

Which way would you choose to test cache expiration and why?

Comment: how is cache_key generated? if you are relying on the default rails code I wouldn't even test that. If you have a custom method to create that cache_key then test that method

Comment: Thank you for your question @arieljuod. I clarified my question